# Update existing property of object if key matches

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create an object like this:

```
type: "asset", value: { long: 1.45, short: 1.67, extendedLong: 2.67 }
```

from this:

```
[{percent: 1.45, type: long, sector: asset}, {percent: 1.67, type: short, sector: asset}, {percent: 2.67, type: extendedLong, sector: asset}
```

I tried an approach of maintaining an object that is empty in the beginning. I was doing something like this:

```
 if (!object[asset]) {
   object[asset] = { long: 1.45 }
  }
 else object[asset] = { short: 1.67}
```

but that is not working out. Can someone please help?

Comment: is that your full attempt, or is asset declared as something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map new objects and assign all to a single object.

```js
var array = [{ percent: 1.45, type: 'long', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 1.67, type: 'short', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 2.67, type: 'extendedLong', sector: 'asset'}],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(({ percent, type }) => ({ [type]: percent })));

console.log(result);
```

For deeper nested objects, you need a differetn approach because an assignment with a nested object, the object deletes the preciously saved nested objects. Instead you could reduce the array and maintain the structure of the wanted result.

```js
var array = [{ percent: 1.45, type: 'long', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 1.67, type: 'short', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 2.67, type: 'extendedLong', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 1.45, type: 'long', sector: 'Convertible' }, { percent: 1.67, type: 'short', sector: 'Convertible' }, { percent: 2.67, type: 'extendedLong', sector: 'Convertible' }],
    result = array.reduce((o, { percent, type, sector }) => {
        o[sector] = o[sector] || {};
        o[sector][type] = percent;
        return o;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that is great approach. I dint know you could do it through assign and array.map. My array contains multiple objects and not all of them are for "asset" though. These 3 objects will be repeated for different "sectors". How would I be able to separate out sectors in this approach and make them a key for the object that we are getting back?

Comment: please add what you have and what you like to get from it.

Comment: I have something like this: array = [{ percent: 1.45, type: 'long', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 1.67, type: 'short', sector: 'asset' }, { percent: 2.67, type: 'extendedLong', sector: 'asset'}, { percent: 1.45, type: 'long', sector: 'Convertible' }, { percent: 1.67, type: 'short', sector: 'Convertible' }, { percent: 2.67, type: 'extendedLong', sector: 'Convertible'},] and I am trying to get:{ asset: {
  "long": 1.45,
  "short": 1.67,
  "extendedLong": 2.67
} , Convertible: {
  "long": 1.45,
  "short": 1.67,
  "extendedLong": 2.67
} } and so on...